# Java Rounding Double

Tags: java, math, rounding

So I'm dealing with a random double, from 1 - 20, however sometimes the double is 8.000091, or something like 9.600191. How would I round it to the nearest whole number? I know there is a Java method, something around Math.round(); but unsure how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not sure? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Rounding it, or printing it with zero digits after the comma?

Comment: Try (int)(x+0.5) or just use `Random`'s `nextInt(20)+1`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `Math.round(Double d)` returns the Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding up.

So just call the `Math.round()` method and send in your result.

The full Math class documentation for Java 7 can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: Hi, So if I do the code, Math.round(myDouble);, and the double is 8.492801, it'll round down to 8?

Comment: Yes. As it says, it rounds to the closest long, which in that case would be 8.

Comment: Quick question, how would I in the future round in to say the nearest 100?

Comment: @Developer42 Not guaranteed to be the best solution, but: Divide the number by 100. Round it. Multiply it by 100.